# python pandas column dtype=object causing merge to fail with: DtypeWarning: Columns have mixed types

Tags: python, pandas, merge, type-conversion

I am trying to merge two dataframes `df1, df2` on `Customer_ID` column. It seems that `Customer_ID` has the same data type (`object`) in both.

df1:

```
Customer_ID |  Flag
12345           A
```

df2:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_Value
12345           258478
```

When I merge the two tables:

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on='Customer_ID', how='left')
```

For some Customer_IDs it worked and for others it didn't. FOr this example, I would get this result:

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_Value | Flag
    12345           258478         NaN
```

I checked the data types and they are the same:

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 873353 entries, 0 to 873352
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Customer_ID    873353 non-null object
Flag      873353 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 20.0+ MB

df2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 873353 entries, 0 to 873352
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Customer_ID    873353 non-null object
Transaction_Value      873353 int64
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 20.0+ MB
```

When I uploaded df1, I did get this message:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2717: DtypeWarning: Columns (1) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

When I wanted to check, if a customer ID exists, I realized that I have to specify it differently in the two dataframes.

```
df1.loc[df1['Customer_ID'] == 12345]

df2.loc[df2['Customer_ID'] == '12345']
```

Comment: I tested it and its working fine, the problem is not with the datatype

Comment: I think the problem is with my column Customer_ID having multiple data types re the error message; how can I fix that?

Comment: @piRSquared just posted an answer to handle that

Comment: **Always include pandas version numbers when reporting version-specific behavior, bugs, features etc.** Looking back at this now, it's impossible to know for sure if this was [version 0.20(.2?)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html), and thus if we're looking at an old fixed bug, or something else.

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['Customer_ID'] == 12345]` implies its dtype is `int` not `object`: which is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Customer_ID` is of `dtype==object` in both cases... But that doesn't mean that the individual elements are the same type.  You need to make both `str` or `int`

---

Using `int`

```
dtype = dict(Customer_ID=int)

df1.astype(dtype).merge(df2.astype(dtype), 'left')

   Customer_ID Flag  Transaction_Value
0        12345    A             258478
```

---

Using `str`

```
dtype = dict(Customer_ID=str)

df1.astype(dtype).merge(df2.astype(dtype), 'left')

   Customer_ID Flag  Transaction_Value
0        12345    A             258478
```

Comment: how do I specify that this is a left merge?

Comment: it doesn't have to us ' ' ? so dtype = dict('Customer_ID'=str)??

Comment: `dtype = {'Customer_ID': str}` or as I had it `dtype = dict(Customer_ID=str)`.  Both are valid.  I have a stylistic preference for the latter.

Comment: I've updated my post to include `'left'`.  It's basically the same merge you were performing.  Just with the `astype`

Comment: hm, the merge isn't working, I do get the columns from df2, but no values in those columns

Comment: could it be related to indexing?

Comment: could it be because I have other columns in the dataframes beyond the ones listed?

Comment: If you have other data or information, you should include it in your question.

Comment: @jeangelj: when in doubt, always specify `how=..., on=...` etc. to `pd.merge()`, don't leave things to chance, that damages reproducibility ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). If you can still reproduce the failure, post your code in an edited update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found the easiest way to merge between two data frame without changing the dtypes.

```
    final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is not optimal or advisable. He needs to change both data types in this case for the merge to work safely. Using concat will force the merge, but you're going to end up with a whole bunch of rows with null.